# VBA Office: Compile error: Next without For

Tags: vba, iteration, office365

I'm not sure what about my code is causing the compile error. I've indented and done everything else I can think of to get it to work but it's not happening. The error in VBA highlights the first next that occurs when finding the average. I'm using an MBP but I doubt that has anything to do with this error.

```
Sub Stdev()

'Declare my variables
Dim N, i, j As Integer
Dim sumofnum, sumofEsq, Xbar, Variance As Double

'Initialize variables to zero
sumofnum = 0
sumofEsq = 0
Xbar = 0
Variance = 0

'Initialize N, the number of measurements in the sample

N = 15

'Calulate the average Xbar using a For Next loop. The i increments by 1 each time through the ‘loop when it reaches the Next statement.

For i = 1 To N
Do Until (Cells(i, 2).Value = False)
    If (Cells(i, 2).Value = True) Then
        sumofnum = sumofnum + (Cells(i, 2).Value)
    End If
        Cells(i, N).Value = 15
Next

'Cells in vba is used to reference the cells in the spreadsheet by (row, column)
Xbar = sumofnum / N

'Calculate the variance. Here i increments across each column in the data.
For j = 1 To N
   sumofEsq = sumofEsq + (Cells(j, 2).Value - Xbar) ^ 2

Next

'Calculate the population standard deviation
‘Variance = sumofEsq / N

'if you want the sample standard deviation
Variance = sumofEsq / (N - 1)
StdDev = Sqr(Variance)
Cells(2, 18).Value = StdDev

End Sub
```

Comment: The Do is missing a Loop Until.  It looks like you have the Until clause following immediately the Do keyword; it needs to be at the end of the block of lines to repeat.

Comment: More precisely, the `Next` at the end of the `Do Until` block should be `Loop`.  `Next` is used with `For` statements.

Answer (score 1):

So, further to my comment.

```
Do Until (Cells(i, 2).Value = False)
    'statements to repeat
Loop
```

Answer (score 1):

Couple of things wrong:

- Your `for` loops need to be ended in a format `Next <what>`
- and your `Do` loops need to be ended with `Loop Until <condition>`

*alternatively `Do Until <condition> ... code.... Loop`*

So your code should look something like this:

```
For i = 1 To N
  Do Until (Cells(i, 2).Value = False)
    If (Cells(i, 2).Value = True) Then
        sumofnum = sumofnum + (Cells(i, 2).Value)
    End If

    Cells(i, N).Value = 15
  Loop 
Next i

'Cells in vba is used to reference the cells in the spreadsheet by (row, column)
Xbar = sumofnum / N

'Calculate the variance. Here i increments across each column in the data.
For j = 1 To N
   sumofEsq = sumofEsq + (Cells(j, 2).Value - Xbar) ^ 2
Next j
```